# Unable to load a file from given path php

Tags: php, jquery, filepath

I am having problems in loading a jpg file path in my php script.I specified the file path correctly because when I enter it in the browser, it shows me the image in the browser.But
when I try to run the script it says

> Unable to open `'http://localhost/php/testig/assets/Others/uploadify/memes/abc100003052455644.jpg'` for writing: Invalid argument

I am returning this path to the client side. So if I use `dirname(__ FILE __)` this works fine but when I try to dynamically change the path of image on client side using jquery.It gives me error saying.

> Not allowed to load local resource

Comment: because it's not `testig` but `testing`?

Comment: try using file_exists check
if(!file_exists($file_path)) exit("no such file with path: " . $file_path);

Comment: @Svetlio it is showing me that the file does not exist. But when I clicked on the link it opens the image in new tab. Why it is not reading here but showing it in the browser with the same url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$current_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$file_path = $current_path . "somefolder/folder2/filename.jpg";
```

Try to catch your file path this way..

At your PHP code you should be working with real paths.

Edit:

```
$www_path = "http://localhost/folder/folder/folder/img.jpg";
```

The first $file_path you can use inside your PHP code (to open/edit/delete your image file inside your PHP code ONLY).

And the $www_path is the path which can be seen from your users and you may put as Image src at your HTML.

Comment: It gives the error on client side `Not allowed to load local resource`.

Comment: When I do this , the php script runs ok but it gives this error on client side for changing the src of the image

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with your `/php/testig/` - this should be `/php/testing/`. A simple typo!

Comment: if you read comments on the question, you will notice that your answer is wrong